# Max of a Collection item?

Tags: c#, collections, struct, norm

I am generating (x,y,z) coordinates in a collection as follows:

```
this.facePoints3D = frame.Get3DShape();

foreach(Vector3DF vector in facePoints3D)  //vector has 121 points
 {
    float zvect = vector.Z           //collect z-points which is made of 121 points
 } 
//where Vector3DF is a struct of floats (x, y, z)
```

The thing is I want to find the L2 norm of the zvect in C#. I have looked around msdn's documentation website and there doesn't seem to be a predefined way to do this.

Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: Where is `Vector3DF` defined? Is it a type from the framework?

Comment: @Codor he said it "Vector3DF is a struct of floats (x, y, z)"

Comment: Oh thanks I was overlooking the comment.

Comment: I was never strong in math, what is a `L2 norm`? What is the desired result, can you explain it in your words with a small example (less than 121 points)?

Comment: @TimSchmelter L2 norm of a vector is its length (if it's 2D or 3D vector). But the title of the question, the code and the comments in it don't really make sense.

Comment: I assume it is the square root of the sum of the squares of the absolutes of the components, as informally explained here http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/65580-what-mean-l2-norm

Comment: (To answer the question title) Maximum length of a collection would be `Int32.MaxValue` which is 2^31 (roughly 2.1 billion)

Comment: Indeed, the comments and the title don't really sum up (pun intended). Could you please rephrase the question a bit for clarification?

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication. Here's an example, the L2-norm of the vector x=(x1,x2,x3) is given by
 |x|=sqrt(x1^2+x2^2+x3^2).

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, the `L2` norm coud be calculated by the following function.

```
float L2Norm(Vector3DF Vec)
{
    return Math.Sqrt( Vec.X * Vec.X + 
                      Vec.Y * Vec.Y + 
                      Vec.Z * Vec.Z );
}
```

Using Linq,, the values for the vectors in the collection can be calculated as follows.

```
foreach (double L2Norm in facePoints3D.Select(L2Norm))
{
    // do something with L2Norm
}
```

Comment: You can skip the `Math.Abs` is this case since it's not a complex vector.

Comment: Thanks but in my case I am interested in the norm of 121 zvects as I typed above.